# can linker omit object file when linking static lib?

Tags: c++, linker

I have a static library (lib.a) and a program that links to it. The library doesn't have any entry point that would always be called before using it, but I need to execute a piece of code very early in the program (preferably before main() starts). Therefore I thought I would use static variable of my own class. I added new source file that contains something like:

```
#include <MyClass.h>
static MyClass myVar;
```

The constructor of MyClass would then execute my code. When I link lib.a and try executing "nm" on it I get information that myVar is there. However, when I link my program and try "nm" on it I do not see myVar. When I put this piece of code into an existing file then the symbol is visible in the final executable. Why is that? Can linker omit object file from lib.a library in this case? I know that the variable is not referenced from outside (it cannot be as it is static) but it should execute code on it's own and therefore I don't get why should it be removed.

In case it makes a difference I'm using some old SunPro compiler.

Comment: Writing code that depends on global variables initialization is a BAD idea. Better thing of how do it better.

Comment: @ybungalobil: It can be useful; for example unit testing. (This is how most C++ unit testing frameworks handle automatic test registration). @Tomasz: What compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: @Billy: It may be useful, but only if at most one component relies on it. Otherwise you can get really bad things (initialization order is undefined). Also he wrote that he uses "old SunPro compiler".

Comment: @ybungalobill: I know it has problems -- however, my point is that it's not always a bad idea. Yes, there are caveats to watch out for, but that doesn't mean noone should ever use the construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what the linker does is pretty standard (I don't mean C++ standard, just generally observer behaviour) and you can work around it. In GNU `ld` it is `--whole-archive` option, in my case of Sun tools it is `-z allextract`. Which didn't actually work as expected for my project, so I used some magic with weak symbols an `-z weakextract` to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, the linker should be forced to include that object file while compiling your program. However, support for this is buggy in many compilers, such as [MSVC++](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users). Adding an external reference somewhere in your main program should force that object file to be included.

Also note that in the case of `nm`, it's possible that your static initializer was inlined, and therefore the symbol need not exist in your final binary. Try something with side effects (such as a `std::cout` statement) in your static, and make sure it doesn't run before blaming the compiler :)

Comment: I know it doesn't work and that is why I started investigating with nm. Thanks for the info that it should normally work, but it would be nice to know whether it is defined by C++/other standard or it just works in other compilers?

Comment: @Tomasz: The C++ standard doesn't say anything about how the final binary is to be assembled. (I.e. the standard does not know the existence of either static or dynamic libraries) This is because the standard is written to be machine neutral, and such libraries aren't possible on many architectures (particularly ones which separate code and data)